# Get all the values of a specific key in a json file

Tags: c#, json

I have a list of strings as follows:

["abc", "def", "ghi"]

I also have a folder which includes 'n' number of json files. Each json file has the following structure:

```
{
  "$schema": "schema.json",
  "actions": [
    {
      "verb": "abc",
      "fieldType": "Text"
    },
    {
      "verb": "def", 
      "subactions": [
        {
          "verb": "ghi",
          "internalName": "PKC_Floor"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "verb": "jkl",
      "displayName": "Home"
    }
  ],
  "bindata": {},
  "version": 2
}
```

How do I get all the values of key "verb" from all json files in c#? In this example, values of key "verb" are abc, def, ghi, jkl.

And check if verbs in json files are a part of the list. If not, display that verb. In this example, "jkl" is not a part of the list. So, output that verb.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/32164/collect-all-fields-of-json-object), we can create a class like:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class JsonFieldsCollector
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, JValue> fields;

    public JsonFieldsCollector(JToken token)
    {
        fields = new Dictionary<string, JValue>();
        CollectFields(token);
    }

    private void CollectFields(JToken jToken)
    {
        switch (jToken.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                foreach (var child in jToken.Children<JProperty>())
                    CollectFields(child);
                break;
            case JTokenType.Array:
                foreach (var child in jToken.Children())
                    CollectFields(child);
                break;
            case JTokenType.Property:
                CollectFields(((JProperty)jToken).Value);
                break;
            default:
                fields.Add(jToken.Path, (JValue)jToken);
                break;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JValue>> GetAllFields() => fields;
}
```

Usage:

```
var json = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var fieldsCollector = new JsonFieldsCollector(json);
var fields = fieldsCollector.GetAllFields().Where(field => field.Key.Contains("verb")).Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, JValue>("verb", f.Value));

foreach (var field in fields)
    Console.WriteLine($"{field.Key}: '{field.Value}'");
```

Output:

```
verb: 'abc'
verb: 'def'
verb: 'ghi'
verb: 'jkl'
```

This requires [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to work

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to include all the code in a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You could first make classes to model your JSON data:

```
public class Subaction
{
    public string Verb { get; set; }
    public string InternalName { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string Verb { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public List<Subaction> Subactions { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class Bindata
{
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("$schema")]
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public Bindata Bindata { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

Then use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your JSON file:

```
var jsonPath = "C:\\sample.json";

var desierializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath));
```

And then using LINQ to [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) the verbs and subverbs, then [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) the results into a final `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
var verbs = desierializedJson.Actions
    .Select(a => new { 
        a.Verb, 
        SubVerbs = a.Subactions != null ? 
            a.Subactions.Select(sb => sb.Verb) :
            Enumerable.Empty<string>() 
    })
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Verb, 1).Concat(x.SubVerbs));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", verbs));
# abc, def, ghi, jkl
```

The above uses a ternary operator to ensure `SubActions` is not `null`, and assigns an `Enumerable.Empty<string>` if is `null`, since some action objects have sub actions and others don't. It also flattens the sub actions from `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` to `IEnumerable<string>` with [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8).

If your not comfortable with using LINQ, you can use regular `foreach` loops as well:

```
var verbs = new List<string>();
foreach (var action in desierializedJson.Actions)
{
    verbs.Add(action.Verb);
    if (action.Subactions != null)
    {
        foreach (var subAction in action.Subactions)
        {
            verbs.Add(subAction.Verb);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", verbs));
# # abc, def, ghi, jkl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Newtonsoft.Json, try deserialize to anonymous object:

```
var example = new
{
    actions = new[] {
        new { verb = "" }
    }
};

var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, example);
var verbs = x.actions.Select(o => o.verb).ToArray();
```